# what is maximum Input voltage for 2s bms

Tags: lithium-ion, ups, step-up, bms

I am making UPS for my 12v broadband router. I am planing to use XL6009 boots converter to booter 8.4 volt to 12v. For charging 2s Li-ion battery with 2s BMS i don't have 8.4v charger. Can I use 12V or 9V 2AMP DC adapter to charge my batteries.

I am using [this BMS](https://robokits.co.in/batteries-chargers/charge-protection-circuit/lifepo4-2s-8a-3.2v-bms-charge-protection-circuit?gclid=CjwKCAjw2a32BRBXEiwAUcugiM_cZGo0iAkihXjd1pU23Azp3gpnz6tU1RZfTnEVDDd_3W26i0I2xxoCxbwQAvD_BwE)

Comment: why not use a converter to supply 8.4V from 12V ?

Comment: I can use it if 2s bms can't handle more than 8.4v.

Comment: "Can I use 12V or 9V 2AMP DC adapter to charge my batteries"_ - No. https://www.powerstream.com/li.htm

Comment: Perhaps you should do some reading about the batteries and what they need.